# How pro-active must we be tracing (non) Jewishness?

Tags: tzibur-community, jewishness

In a "[hypothetical](https://www.timesofisrael.com/listen-lawyer-fights-back-after-3-generations-of-immigrants-declared-not-jewish/)" case in which an entire family is declared retroactively not Jewish from 3 generations ago, how active must the community be in tracing all the people who would have, could have and might be affected by this decision? Children, schools, relatives, community members would have been affected. It seems that most anyone affected in the past would be an anoos (but would anyone lose a schar mitzvah which was gained when relying on someone not Jewish, like for a minyan, or the blowing of the shofar?) But must a declaration be made so future communities would know a changed status, future suitors would know that the girls are not Jewish? Does a local ruling have to be disseminated to extended family which branched off 3 generations ago? Whose responsibility would that be?

Conversely, if we find that someone IS Jewish, would we have to trace all family members who are now Jewish and tell them (turning them into intentional sinners if they don't care) or let them continue to be anoosim? Whose job is that?

Comment: IINM a person who converted can declare that his own conversion was invalid, thereby forbidding himself to marry into the congregation (הפה שהתר הוא הפה שאסר) but that bears no legal significance on his children who remain in their presumed status of being born Jewish. Perhaps a similar concept extends here?